# How do I rewrite these TRIM Access queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, trim

I am rewriting more code from Access to SQL Server and I have never encountered a TRIM code before, any ideas how to write it for SQL Server as far as I know there is not just plain TRIM for SQL Server

```
Trim([FCT_TYP_CD]) & " (" & Trim([Dep_TYP_CD]) & ")" AS [Course Owner]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  RTRIM(LTRIM([FCT_TYP_CD])) + ' (' + 
        RTRIM(LTRIM([Dep_TYP_CD])) + ')' AS [Course Owner]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, idk what I would do without this site.!

Answer (score 1):

```
LTRIM(@String)
RTRIM(@string)
```

or

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(@string))
```